# Predicting the magnetic behaviour of Mn doped SmFeO3

Tags: anti-ferromagnetic, pymatgen

I am trying to predict the magnetic order transformations in Mn doped SmFeO3 using the MagneticStructureEnumerator class of pymatgen.
Attached is the error message:

```py
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-4d89c9b376bb> in <module>
     37 from pymatgen.transformations.advanced_transformations import MagOrderingTransformation     
38 mag_par = MagOrderingTransformation({"Sm3+":5,"Fe3+":5,"O2-":0,"Mn3+":4}, order_parameter=0.5)
---> 39 SmFeO3_Mn_Mag_new = mag_par.apply_transformation(SmFeO3_Mn_prop)    
40 print(SmFeO3_Mn_Mag_new)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymatgen\transformations\advanced_transformations.py in apply_transformation(self, structure, return_ranked_list)   
940         t = EnumerateStructureTransformation(**enum_kwargs)   
941     
--> 942         alls = t.apply_transformation(structure, return_ranked_list=return_ranked_list)
    943 
    944         # handle the fact that EnumerateStructureTransformation can either

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymatgen\transformations\advanced_transformations.py in apply_transformation(self, structure, return_ranked_list)
    445             )   
446             try:
--> 447                 adaptor.run()   
 448             except EnumError:   
 449                 warn("Unable to enumerate for max_cell_size = {}".format(max_cell_size))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymatgen\command_line\enumlib_caller.py in run(self)    
140             self._gen_input_file()    
141             # Perform the actual enumeration
--> 142             num_structs = self._run_multienum()
143             # Read in the enumeration output as structures.    
144             if num_structs > 0:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymatgen\command_line\enumlib_caller.py in _run_multienum(self)    
292     def _run_multienum(self):    
293 
--> 294         p = subprocess.Popen([enum_cmd],    
295                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE,    
296                              stdin=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)

~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)    
852                             encoding=encoding, errors=errors    
853
--> 854             self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,   
855                                 pass_fds, cwd, env,   
856                                 startupinfo, creationflags, shell,

~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)  
1305             # Start the process  
1306             try:
-> 1307                 hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,  
1308                                          # no special security 
1309                                          None, None,
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: The discussion here has been moved to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58630438#58630438)

Comment: It seems like you resolved this issue, based on your question a few days later about using the code. Would you be able to add an answer explaining what the issue was and how you fixed it?

Comment: This question has been closed as it seems to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone wants to add an answer or the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.